# Color the edges and diagonals of a regular polygon

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Here is the problem:

For what $n$ is it possible to color the edges and diagonals of an $n$-side regular polygon with $\dfrac{\binom{n}{2}}{3}$ colors, such that you use every color exactly three times and for every color the three segments (edges or diagonals) with that color form a triangle?

Trivially $n\equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod{3}$. I can also prove that if the statement is true for $k$ than it is true for $3k$ as well. How to finish? Please help! Thanks

Comment: Even assuming "polyhpn" in the title is a typo for  *polygon*, it is unclear what you mean by "the edges and sides".  Aren't the side of a regular polygon the same as the edges?  A regular $n$-sided polygon has $n$ edges.

Comment: $n$ needs to be odd; focusing on a vertex, $v$, the $n-1$ edges out of $v$ are divided into same-colored pairs.

Comment: See http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/7160-17/slides/04SteinerTripleSystems.pdf for a construction