# A game with rounds containing four people

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given $n$ people playing a game. In every round we choose exactly four people and each pair of them play with each other. Our claim is that every pair of people play exactly once againts each other. For what $n$ is it possible?

I have proved that $n\equiv 0/1/4/9 \pmod{12}$. But is it always possible? Please help to find constructions if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can 0 people play exactly once?

Comment: Trivially $n\geq 4$

Comment: Can you use the logic in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874321/color-the-edges-and-diagonals-of-a-regular-polygon#comment5933073_2874321) to rule out $n\equiv_{12} 0,9$?

Comment: Can you explain your solution for $n=13$ ? There are $7 \times 13=91$ possible pairs, but if there are $6$ matches in each round then after $15$ rounds at least one pair is omitted and after $16$ rounds at least five pairs play each other twice. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: You should look into Steiner systems. Your previous question was about Steiner Triple Systems S(2,3,n), while this question is about S(2,4,n).

Comment: @gandalf61 $\binom{13}2=13\times 6$.

Comment: True ! My bad. And that explains where the $0,1,4,9 \mod 12$ restriction comes from.